# Why is this redirection not working in my zsh script?

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

I have a zsh script which includes the line

```
rm *original    > /dev/null  2>&1
```

but when those files aren't there, I get

```
no matches found: *original
```

to the terminal/screen.

Now, I've been retired for ten years, but memory tells me that has worked before in other shells.  How is zsh different?  I did a web search for "zsh redirection," but got pages on bash instead.

Comment: The number of times I had to change that title _without_ changing its meaning was ridiculous.

Comment: This explains it https://superuser.com/questions/1607629/how-to-suppress-error-messages-in-zsh

Comment: The error message isn't coming from `rm`, but from the shell itself. You would have to redirect the *shell's* standard error.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313187/22257.

Comment: Both of those links explain it well.  I should have known that, but I'll stick to my lame excuse of being retired so long.  :-)